# Elegant callback binding when using promises and prototypes in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype, promise

I am an heavy javascript prototypes and promises user.

My problem is that I need to use `.bind(this)` to set the right context about every time I *thenify* my promises.

Here is a sample code showing the problem ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sozige/2/edit?js,console)):

```
var Q = require('Q');

var AsyncCounter = function(initialValue){
  this.value = initialValue;
};

AsyncCounter.prototype.increment=function(){
  return Q.fcall(function(){
    return ++this.value;
  }.bind(this));
};

AsyncCounter.prototype.decrement=function(){
  return Q.fcall(function(){
    return --this.value;
  }.bind(this));
};

var counter = new AsyncCounter(10);

counter.increment()
  .then(function(incrementedValue){
    console.log('incremented value:', incrementedValue)
  })
  .then(counter.decrement.bind(counter))
  .then(function(decrementedValue){
    console.log('decremented value:', decrementedValue)
  });
```

See how often I have to rely on `bind()`? I find it too unelegant.

I do know about [petkaantonov/bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) promise library and its very useful [`bind(scope)`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#binddynamic-thisarg---promise) function that propagate the scope on callbacks but I feel like there is a better, *native* way to do it.

Does anybody have a proper way to do it?

Comment: Don't use Q, use Bluebird, Bluebird has a `.bind` method which solves this problem. The ultimate solution would be ES6 arrows but we don't have those yet. With Bluebird your code would have been `Promise.bind(counter).then(counter.increment).then(counter.decremenent)`

Comment: What is your actual use case? Are these `Q.fcall`s only examples for an actually asynchronous functions, and do you only care for the `.bind()` in the `then` chain? If not, you should notice that it might be not the best practice to mutate instances asynchronously.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You might not have read my question entirely but I know about bluebird and its bind() function. That's my go-to library but I want a generic solution for any promise library.

Comment: @Bergi This is obviously not a real usual use case. An actual use case would be defining [Parse.com objects](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-classes) functions, but again, my goal is ton find the best generic way ton conciliate prototypes and promises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember when you learned about `Foo.prototype.bar=function(){...}` and turned your back on defining methods inside the constructor as `this.bar = function(){...}`?  The reasons were speed, and efficiency of memory.

Well now you have good reason to turn the clock back and sacrifice speed/efficiency in order to achieve "detachable" methods - ie methods that are specific to *their instance* of the constructor with `this` ready bound, which is exactly what you want.

If the methods are called many times, then the inefficiency of construction will be more than compensated for by not having to use `bind()` when referring to the function. Plus you get the syntactic convenience you seek.

Here's a version of your example re-jigged to better demonstrate the syntactic convenience :

```
var AsyncCounter = function(value){

    this.increment = function(){
      return Q.fcall(function(){
        return console.log("++value: " + ++value);
      }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this);

    this.decrement = function(){
      return Q.fcall(function(){
        return console.log("--value: " + --value);
      }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this);
};

var counter = new AsyncCounter(10);

counter.increment()
  .then(counter.decrement)
  .then(counter.increment);
```

In summary, you need to do two things :

- define methods *inside* the constructor
- bind `this` to the methods.

Comment: I think we can go further by removing all references to `this.value` and save `value` as a scoped variable instead. Great answer.

Comment: I just wrote a new version of your code with improvement described in my previous comment. Would you mind updating your answer so I can mark it as `answered`? Here's the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/sozige/3/edit?js,console)

Comment: OK done. You'll see I obviated the assignment by incrementing/derementing the formal parameter `value`, which is fine as long as you don't need to recall the initial value.

Comment: You can remove the remaining `.bind(this)`, they are useless now. Also, just polishing it, don't return `console.log`, but return the value itself.

Comment: Mmm, yes the final binds are not now needed in this case but for people reading this in the future ....

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong, the final binds are necessary as the inner binds depend on them.

Comment: Sure but unless you want to refer to the instance inside the async function you don't need them to be bound. So you don't need bind at all.

Comment: Arnaud, to demonstrate the principle of detachability, in full, there must be at least one `this` in each method. If `this` had been completely missing at the outset, then you wouldn't have needed to ask the question :)

Answer (score 1):

I think another way to do it is by taking advantage of closures. Every callback that is used in the promise can contain references to some variables of the root scope where it was created.

Normally what most of the people do is to create a variable called `self` that maintans a reference to the outer `this`. So wherever you execute the function of the promise, the closure will maintain the reference and therefore be able to access the scope.

```
AsyncCounter.prototype.increment=function(){
   var self = this;
   return Q.fcall(function(){
    return ++self .value;
  });
};
```

Honestly, I'm not sure which one is more elegant. I'm not sure if there are any other ways of doing what you want without using this technique or the `bind` method.

Comment: The good ol' `var that = this` trick, I should have talk about it.

I sometimes use it but that's not really better than binding. Thanks for your solution, I'll wait for a better answer though.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution in my opinion is to add a `context` method to promises to specify the `this` for function calls in future `then` invocations. This is something I seem to recall having seen in some libraries, can't remember where, and implemented in my own as well. The idea is to write

```js
promise.context(this).then(myfunc)
```

I don't know Q, so I don't know if it would be easy or even possible to extend it/customize it to have this behavior. Here is a toy implementation of this idea using native JS promises:

```
Promise.prototype.context = function (ctxt) { this.ctxt = ctxt; return this; }

Promise.prototype.then = (function() {
    var old_then = Promise.prototype.then;
    return function(fulfill, reject) {
        return old_then.call(this,
            fulfill && fulfill.bind && fulfill.bind(this.ctxt),
            reject  && reject.bind  && reject.bind(this.ctxt)
        );
    };
}());
```

Actually, you can often write your code so that it doesn't end up littered with `context` calls, by doing it once where you create the promise. So:

```
var MyTrip = {
    gotoMars: function() { return InterPlanetaryTrip(Mars).context(this); },
    report:   function() { console.log("I'm back, Mom!"); },
    go:       function() { gotoMars.then(this.report).then(this.drink); }
};
```

This approach saved me boundless aggravation and has zero downsides that I can see. I cannot see a more "native" way to do this, whatever that might mean.

#### Less intrusive approach?

As a more direct answer to your question, you could possibly introduce a small bit of sugar--a method which binds and calls `Q.fcall` in one fell swoop, as follows:

```
AsyncCounter.prototype.fcall = function(fn) { 
    return Q.fcall(fn.bind(this)); 
};

AsyncCounter.prototype.increment = function() { 
    return this.fcall(function() {
        return ++this.value;
    });
};
```

Comment: I think that's very similar to what `bluebird` library does in its `bind()` function. I think it's a good solution even if I am looking for a more native way of doing it.

Comment: @ArnaudRinquin Can you elaborate on what "native" means for you?

Comment: Minimum boilerplate, simplest, cleaner, more generic way to do it.

Comment: I really like the _less intrusive_ approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ES6 you could use arrow functions and use the lexical scope.

```
AsyncCounter.prototype.increment = () => {
    return Q.fcall(() => ++this.value);
};
```